# Bouncycastle and S/MIME signing-time attribute

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, signing

I am kind of new to signing / certificate but after checking Google + SO, I can't find an answer.
I have the base code for generating the signature for a file for PKCS #7 detached signature, and everything so far is good... The client that verify the signature is happy with the signature generated. 
I have now a new requirement to include the date/time that the original file was signed using the S/MIME signing-time attribute.

My code so far for dealing with it is:

```
    final Attribute signingAttribute = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.signingTime, new DERSet(new DERUTCTime(new Date()))); 
    signedAttributes.add(new Attribute(CMSAttributes.contentType, new DERSet(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"))));
    signedAttributes.add(new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(hash))));
    signedAttributes.add(signingAttribute);
    final AttributeTable signedAttributesTable = new AttributeTable(signedAttributes);
    final DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator signedAttributeGenerator = new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(signedAttributesTable);
    // now proceed for the signing process with BouncyCastle
    final JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder().setProvider("BC").setDirectSignature(true);
    builder.setSignedAttributeGenerator(signedAttributeGenerator);
    final SignerInfoGenerator signerGenerator = builder.build("SHA1withRSA", key, cert);

    final CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    ...
```

Then the code afterward is the same that I used to have for generating the signature... But doesn't work.

One thing that I am not really is for the hash for the messageDigest:

```
    signedAttributes.add(new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(hash))));
```

I got the hash generated as:

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1", "BC");
    md.update(fileToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    hash = md.digest();
```

but I am absolutely not sure that it's the right way to get the hash? And the overall way to get the  S/MIME signing-time attribute generated...

Any hints or overall explanation on what I missed will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

OK after digging more into the code the solution is easy... 
First the code can be simplify and the issue is not at all related to the hash.

For getting the signing time, we can only have one attribute:

```
final ASN1EncodableVector signedAttributes = new ASN1EncodableVector();
final Attribute signingAttribute = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.signingTime, new DERSet(new DERUTCTime(new Date()))); 
signedAttributes.add(signingAttribute);
// Create the signing table
final AttributeTable signedAttributesTable = new AttributeTable(signedAttributes);
// Create the table table generator that will added to the Signer builder
final DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator signedAttributeGenerator = new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(signedAttributesTable);


final JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
builder.setSignedAttributeGenerator(signedAttributeGenerator); 
// ****** DO NOT call: setDirectSignature(true); *****
final SignerInfoGenerator signerGenerator = builder.build("SHA1withRSA", key, cert);
```

The critical piece here is in the commented part:

```
// ****** DO NOT call: setDirectSignature(true); *****
```

If calling setDirectSignature(true), that basically undo all the work done prior. According to the documentation:

> If the passed in flag is true, the signer signature will be based on the data, not a 
>   collection of signed attributes, and no signed attributes will be included.

So that's it... from then on the signature generated will have the signing time...

I verified with my new client, and the previous error/log I was getting is gone

Comment: Hello Yoda, I'm guessing you managed to use a PKCS#7 (with only the public key) to sign / encrypt a SMIME message that's send to someone who owns the private key. I'm stuck on that problem and maybe you can send me an extract of your code doing this ? Thanks for your help !